# How to get separator between buttons

Tags: android, button, layout, separator

How can i have separator between buttons. Below is the screenshot and code

[image]

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Activity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Support"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/support"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Messages"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: seperate in the sense you want show some gap or any seperator image you have?

Comment: use android:layout_margin = "10dp"

Comment: see my answer it will solve your problem i tested on my machine.

Comment: let me know if any issue come

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use views to create deviders , changes margins params according to you

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="#899909"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/status"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: one more solution is dont add the views only.. set margins directly to 
      buttons. so u can skip some views loading in to memory.

Answer (score 1):

You just add view with the attributes **android:layout_width="2dp"** and **android:layout_height="fill_parent"** and **android:background="color or images"**

Answer (score 0):

You can use border to right side only : Try this code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: add to button android:background="@drawable/border"

Answer (score 0):

Place this in between each button.

```
<View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="2px"
    android:background="#90909090"/>
```

should give you a slim grayish vertical bar.

Comment: I know it can be done using View but if i use the code that u have shared it will give messy output....

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:-

Use this code:--

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
     >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/support"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Messages"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kailash, this seems to be fine but if i want to use height in separator and make it look alike exactly like screenshot, it won't work, for example i used "height=1dip" but it didn't made separator to look alike image

Comment: means you need some margin from top and bottom in seperator?

Comment: Ohh should MarginTop and MarginBottom work for that ? lemme try

Comment: give padding in tablerow you will get exactly what you want

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer if this solved your problem.